# How to include a PHP page to another page's div?

Tags: php, ajax

I want that only my website's content change and the header and footer to be in a fixed position. I read very much about it, but I can't find a solution.
I've made an `include()` for the header and footer, and the site's content comes into a `<div>`. 
But I can't handle the PHP codes inside the div. I have a login system and when I include the PHP file, before and after login contents can be seen at the same time.
What's wrong with my code?

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prev_id = 'h10';
var now_id = '';
function change(menuID)
{ // Mozilla and Friends
  now_id = menuID;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
          if (window.ActiveXObject)
          { // Internet Explorer
                        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
        req.onreadystatechange = processChoices;
        req.open("GET", "change.php?menuID="+menuID+"", false);
        req.send(null);
}
function processChoices()
{ // wait until the request is done
        if (req.readyState == 4)
        { // Make sure request came back OK
                if (req.status == 200)
                {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = req.responseText;
      prev_id = now_id;
    }
        else
                { alert("Nem lehet betölteni" + req.statusText); }
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="modosit('h10')">
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <div id="content" class="content"></div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

change.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plan; charset=utf-8");
$page = '';
$pg = isset($_GET['menuID']) ? $_GET['menuID'] : 'h10';
switch ($pg) {
  case "h10":
    $page = 'about.php';
    break;
  case "h11":
    $page = 'contact.php';
    break;
  default:
    $page = about.php';
}
echo file_get_contents($page);
?>
```

Comment: replace `echo file_get_contents($page);` with `include $page;`

Comment: aside: you've got a missing quote mark here: `$page = about.php';` ... I assume that's just on SO and not in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

change `echo file_get_contents($page);` to `include $page;`